# Linux Bash how to grab output and put it back in the script using for loop

Tags: linux, bash, indirection

Variable's value in bash can be easily called with `echo $var` command like this

```
user@linux:~$ a=1; b=2; c=a+b
user@linux:~$ echo $a $b $c
1 2 a+b
user@linux:~$
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to replace `x` with the actual value in `a,b,c`

```
user@linux:~$ a=1; b=2; c=a+b
user@linux:~$ for i in a b c; do echo "$i = x"; done
a = x
b = x
c = x
user@linux:~$
```

By using similar `for` loop, I hope I can get an output like this

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a+b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *indirection*:

```
$ for i in a b c; do echo "$i = ${!i}"; done
a = 1
b = 2
c = a+b
```

#### Documentation

*Indirection* is explained in `man bash`:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and
>   parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of variable 
>   indirection.  Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest
>   of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then
>   expanded and that value   is used in the rest of the substitution,
>   rather than the value of parameter itself.  This is known as indirect
>   expansion.   If  parameter  is  a   nameref, this expands to the name
>   of the variable referenced by parameter instead of performing the
>   complete indirect expansion.  The exceptions
>    to this are the expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described
>   below.  The exclamation point must immediately  follow  the  left 
>   brace  in  order to introduce indirection.